# Windows Forms label custom control origin change

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a custom control derived from a label.
I need to change the native control's location origin from upper left to lower left.

Is there a method or property to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want the Location property to specify the position of the bottom-left corner of the label, instead of the top-left corner?

Comment: Maybe you could explain *why* you want to do this. We be able to suggest a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I have an external file with layout data of controls created by another system, this file position location data is based on the lower left of the control. I have to read it in and render the controls at exact locations based on the file. So for a text label position 100,100 I need to have 100,100 location be the lower left corner of the control. I also need to allow users to mess around with the controls on the screen change locations and then save back to the file all controls origin based on the lower left.

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextAlign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.textalign.aspx) property should do what you need.

```
label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
```

If you're trying to make the `Location` property reflect the bottom-right corner of the control rather than the top-left, then this isn't possible. You can, however, create your own property:

```
public Point BottomLeft
{
    get { return new Point(Left, Bottom); }
    set { Location = new Point(value.X, value.Y - Height); }
}
```

Bear in mind, though, that this won't remain true if the `Height` property changes (you'll have to set it again).

Comment: I don't think that changes the control location origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behavior of the `Label.Location` property so that it refers to the bottom-left corner of the label, you could override `InitLayout()` in your custom label:

```
class myLabel : Label
{
    protected override void InitLayout()
    {
        base.InitLayout();
        Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - Height);                
    }
}
```

This will shift the control up based on the height of the control. So if you start with (100,100) and the label height is 13, you will end with (100,87), which puts the bottom-left corner at (100,100).

But this will only happen when the label is added to a container. If you change the Location of the label after adding it to a container, it will go back to the top-right corner.

The other thing you might try is overriding `LayoutEngine { get; }` of the container which the label is in, so that you have full control over how the Location property of any custom label placed in the container is interpreted.

Comment: Not sure that will help, you are changing the location.  I need the location of the control to point to the lower left.  So if I add the control to the form at Location (100,100) I need location 100,100 to be the lower left corner of the control.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You don't want the actual value of **Location** to change. My suggestion will change **Location.Y**. If that's a deal-breaker, you might have to implement your own LayoutEngine, or mess around with the label's **OnPaint()**.

Comment: But I'm not sure that you can paint outside the bounds of the control.